# Radius of convergence - $\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{1}{a-b}\bigg(\frac{1}{(b-z_0)^{k+1}}-\frac{1}{(a-z_0)^{k+1}}\bigg)(z-z_0)^k$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $0<a<b$, $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}-\{a,b\}$ and $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)}$. Find the power serie of this function and the radius of convergence.

I found the serie $$\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{1}{a-b}\bigg(\frac{1}{(b-z_0)^{k+1}}-\frac{1}{(a-z_0)^{k+1}}\bigg)(z-z_0)^k.$$

However, I don't know how to find the radius of convergence of this serie. I thought I could use the ratio test, but it's a bit more complicated that what I thought. Is anyone could help me at this point

Comment: Your series can be written as a sum of two geometrical series. Find the convergence region for of each of them seperately. If the full series is to converge then both of these two series have to converge.

Comment: @Winther AAAAAH, I understand... it is probably the infimum between those two radius of convergence. Thanks

Comment: Yes. This can also be understood from the fact that $f(z)$ is analytical for $z\not = a,b$. The convergence radius will therefore be the minimum distance from $z_0$ to either of the poles at $a,b$.